# Most efficient way to replace a line in a text document ?

Tags: c, file, unix, text, text-processing

I am learning to code in Unix with C. So far I have written the code to find the index of the first byte of the line that I want to replace. The problem is that sometimes, the number of bytes replacing the line might be greater than the number of bytes already on the line. In this case, the code start overwriting the next line. I came up with two standard solutions:

a) Rather than trying to edit the file in-place, I could copy the entire file into memory, edit it by shifting all the bytes if necessary and rewriting it back to file.

b) Only copy the line I want to end-of-file to memory and edit.

Both suggestions doesn't scale well. And I don't want to impose any restrictions on the line size(like every line must be 50 bytes or something). Is there any efficient way to do the line replacement ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is no less problematic if the replacement is shorter, since there is no way to delete a character in the middle of a file.

Comment: @rici I guess I could replace the remaining characters with spaces...

Answer (score 1):

Copy the first part of the file to a new file (no need to read it all into memory). Then, write the new version of the line. Finally, copy the final part of the file. Swap files and done.

Comment: Nice and terse!  Basic design that well handles all sorts of file sizes and errors.